# Is it possible to change the damage of the Fat Man globally with console commands?

Tags: fallout-4, cheats

In Fallout 4, I don't care to use the Fat Man and I don't want it used on me. I would settle for reducing its damage and radius. I don't mind just typing in a console command when I start the game. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you would have to go into F04 edit to make a global change like that.

The majority of console commands are about the player, immediate NPCs, or spawning objects. If you don't want to get that in-depth to make this change, you could always compromise by using the targetID.kill command to kill enemies that possess a Fat Man.